# Слово "опека"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Недавно встретилось в книге слово "опёка". Именно так, через ё. Правильно ли это? Или все-таки "опека"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно оп**е**ка [не оп**ё**ка].

Answer (score 0):

Фразу приведите целиком.
В значениях "попечение" и "охрана прав" - опека.
Опёка - это, возможно, термин пекарей и всяких там кондитеров. Хотя не уверен.